# java.lang.nullpointerexception at android.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerList

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi i'm new in android i wanted to add a NavDrowerList to my application but it always craches here is my code

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import com.calyos.child.ring.android.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;
 import com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.R;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

  }
```

it always return me "java.lang.nullpointerexception at android.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerList" so i cant figureout if the problem is from the version of android or something else

Comment: post all other code, so i can check

Comment: post log cat and after the caused by nullpointer exception at you will see a pointer to a line of code of your project  post this snippet of code to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to stack overflow, please include more in your question next time or edit your current post. What have you tried? where do you think the issue lies? etc.

Looking at your code it looks like you create navDrawerItems here and then assign it:

```
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}
```

navDrawerItems is declared but doesn't contain any references to any values, just a type, you then go and assign that to the field navDrawerItems. It is likely happening that a call to operate on navDrawerItems such as the getter is trying to get on navDrawerItems which is null. You need to make your class more robust by accounting for null variables such as checking if navDrawerItems is null, if so throw an exception and handle it, otherwise attempt to get the value. for example:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    try {
       return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
       Log.d("YourApp","navDrawerItems is null");
    }
}
```

You can learn more about robust classes [here](https://sites.google.com/site/ubccpsc2102013w2/schedule/ubc-cpsc-210-robust-classes.pdf?attredirects=0&d=1). Ideally you want to be able to handle all possible inputs and account for all possible corresponding outcomes. Don't rely on your program passing proper input to your method, think of all the cases that exist.

Answer (score 0):

please see from below code

```
    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}